# continuous serialization of a list with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am trying to serialize a List to a file in C# with JSON.NET.
I want to be able to add values to the list and serialize that change.

I do not want to serialize the list all over again, since it can grow pretty big.

Is something like that possible with JSON.NET?

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"c:\list.json", FileMode.CreateNew))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(jw, list);
}
```

this way it would only be possible to "Reserialize" the whole list, not add changes to the file.

Comment: you should then manually handle this - json.net's serialization is pretty much atomic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many formats (including json and xml), there is semantic closing of the document at the end; to "append" would require back-tracking through this. In others, there may be length-prefix data **much** earlier in the file that requires changing. In either event, this will only work reasonably if the list is the last (or only) thing in the file - not a safe assumption in the general case, so serializers don't generally include support for "append at the end" after the fact.

My default answer here, therefore, would be:

> either reserialize the entire list, or construct some mechanism of "framing" that allows you to store (and subsequently merge) multiple completely independent fragments (without mutating / extending - just add an extra frame)

Note that some formats *do* support append; for example, protocol buffers deliberately includes no document closing / length preamble - it is a specific feature of the design that append fragment === merge, which for lists means: add an item. However, this is then not json.

Comment: thats pretty much of what i feared. Will look into the protocol buffers, perhaps that's more of what im looking for then.

Comment: @Visions let me know if you need any samples to go with that

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a file format that can be appended to incrementally. A few ideas:

1. Use a different format altogether, like an embedded database.
2. The file probably looks like `[ {item1}, {item2}, ...]`. Delete the last character of the file, append a single item and add the `]` back.